# Why can't I multi-declare a class

Tags: c++

I can do this

```
extern int i;
extern int i;
```

But I can't do the same with a class

```
class A {
..
}
class A {
..
}
```

While in both cases no memory is being allocated.

Comment: Are they supposed to be two difference classes? or a partial class ?

Comment: @all

Actually my understanding is that the differentiating fact between a definition and declaration is - no memory is allocated in latter. That's why I regarded class A{..} to be more of a declaration than a definition.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The following are **declarations**:

```
extern int i;
class A;
```

And the next two are  **definitions**:

```
int i;
class A { ... };
```

The rules are:

- a definition is also a declaration.
- you have to have 'seen' a declaration of an item before you can use it.
- re-declaration is OK (must be identical).
- re-definition is an error (the One Definition Rule).

Comment: You said it better.  I withdraw my answer

Comment: For what it's worth, this is called the One Definition Rule.

Comment: You could add that

    "class A;"

Is, in fact, the declaration of the class A.

Comment: wheres the semicolon?

Comment: as in class A { ... };

Comment: @HenkHolterman the question is labeled C++, I think youre doing C#?

Comment: The third edition of A Tour of C++ has what he calls a class declaration in a header but it has its data members declared in braces. The only difference is that it also has member function declarations (definitions provided in a separate source file). Does that change what's in the header from being a definition to a declaration?

Answer (score 3):

The closest equivalent to `extern int i` with a class is a forward declaration, which you can do as many times as you like:

```
class A;

class A;

class A;

class A{};
```

When you define the actual class you *are* saying how much memory is required to construct an instance of it, as well as how that memory is laid out. That's not really the issue here, though.

Answer (score 2):

The first (extern) makes a reference to an existing variable. So you are just indicating the variable twice.

The class declaration gives meaning to a type (your class: A). You are trying to give two meanings to A. This is not of any use for you, and can only confuse, so the compiler protects you from it.

Btw, if you put both classes in difference namespaces you can give them the same name.

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
class A;
```

as often as you want and then in one file define it with

```
class A { ... }
```

Example for this:
classB.h:

```
class A;
class B { A *a; }
```

classA.h:

```
class B;
class A { B *b; }
```

Comment: That won't work: the compiler needs to see the definition of 'B' to work out the size of 'A'. Pointers or references would work fine, though.

Comment: @roger: thanks, corrected. My C++ knowledge is a little rusty

Answer (score 1):

You can *declare* a class and an object multiple times, what you can't do is *define* it more than once.

`extern` makes this a declaration and not a definition (because there is no initializer):

```
extern int a;
```

The body makes your `class` a definition and not just a declaration. You can define a class once.

Comment: More precisely extern is about linkage. There can be definition with extern, like extern int a = 7;

Comment: Yes, but in this case the more important effect of the `extern` is the fact that it changes the declaration to not be a definition.

Answer (score 0):

But in the first case ther is no contradiction.

```
extern int i;
extern double i;
```

won't work either.
So if you create class A to times it wouldn't be possible to decide who A is.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the real question is 'why would you want to?'. The situation sometimes arises when you include a header file multiple times in the same translation unit (.cpp file). If this is the case, you should look at using [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) to keep the compiler happy.

Another reason that this might be causing problems for you is that you're using a 3rd-party library which defines classes whose names conflict with your own classes. In this case you should look at using namespaces to resolve the ambiguity.

In both cases 'extern int i;' is referencing the same object (declared elsewhere) and so the multiple declarations are unambiguous. If you wrote:

```
extern int i;
extern float i;
```

The compiler would complain about the ambiguity (because it wouldn't know which variable you intended to manipulate if you wrote 'i=0;'.

Duplicate class declarations gives rise to the possibility that declarations are different; again, how would the compiler know which one to use when it encounters 'A foo;'? I guess the compiler could compare the class declarations and verify that they're infact identical, but this would be an awful lot of effort to go to when the alternative solutions (namespaces, include guards, renaming) are so much easier (and probably less confusing for whoever ends up reading the code).

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with declarations vs definitions. The issue is types versus objects.

```
extern int i;
```

tells the program that at an object of type `int` exists, and its name is `i`. Because it is `extern` no storage is allocated for it *here*, but somewhere else, probably in another translation unit, it is defined and storage is allocated for it.

```
class A {
..
};
```

defines a *type* named `A`. It doesn't allocate any objects or variables. It makes absolutely no difference at runtime, and no storage is allocated for it, because it is not an object. It simply introduces a new *type* to the compiler. From this point on, you are able to create objects of type  `A`, and *they* will have storage allocated for them.

Answer (score 0):

I gave it some thought. I realized class in not a data type, it is a enabler for defining a data type.

So in

```
extern int i;
extern int i;
```

int is a data type. So we are re-declaring a variable not a data type.

But in

```
class A {...};
class A {...};
```

A is a data type. And we are re-defining a data type, which is not allowed, of course.