# Why can classes be defined in header files?

Tags: c++, class, header-files

According to [Why can't I multi-declare a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198316/why-cant-i-multi-declare-a-class)

> `class A`; is a declaration while
>
> `class A { ... }` is a definition

Typically, in header files, we define the class and we implement its member functions in the `.cpp`. But wouldn't defining classes in the header file violate the One Definition Rule?

According to https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/89-class-code-and-header-files/

> **Doesn’t defining a class in a header file violate the one-definition rule?**
>
> It shouldn’t. If your header file has proper header guards, it
>   shouldn’t be possible to include the class definition more than once
>   into the same file.
>
> Types (which include classes), are exempt from the
>   part of the one-definition rule that says you can only have one
>   definition per program. Therefore, there isn’t an issue #including
>   class definitions into multiple code files (if there was, classes
>   wouldn’t be of much use).

While the first part is obviously true, header guards will prevent multiple definitions in the same file, but I am confused about the second part of the answer that addresses my question.

If a header file has a definition of a class, for example `ThisClass`, and that header file is included in two other files for example `a.cpp` and `b.cpp`. Why wouldn't it violate the One Definition Rule? If a `ThisClass` object is created in either file, which definition would be called?

Comment: The functions will be inline if defined inside the class definition.

Comment: The header guard part is the wrong reason. You are correct to question this.

Comment: @drescherjm I know that class member functions if defined in the header file are inline, but I am still defining a class right? where class ThisClass {}; would appear twice (referencing my ex)

Comment: Does not violate ODR: _"...each definition consists of the same sequence of tokens (typically, appears in the same header file)..."_ source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition

Comment: @RichardCritten is that saying that if the definitions are identical, ODR isn't violated? (not familiar with meaning of tokens)

Comment: Note: There can be more than one definition in a program of each of the following: class type, enumeration type, inline function, inline variable (since C++17), templated entity (template or member of template, but not full template specialization), as long as all of the following is true: ... https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there no multiple definition error when you define a class in a header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654377/why-is-there-no-multiple-definition-error-when-you-define-a-class-in-a-header-fi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If a header file has a definition of a class, for example ThisClass, and that header file is included in two other files for example a.cpp and b.cpp. Why wouldn't it violate the One Definition Rule?

Because, as you quoted, the one definition rule specifically allows for this.

How can it? Read on…

> If a ThisClass object is created in either file, which definition would be called?

It doesn't matter, because the definitions are required to be absolutely, lexically identical.

If they're not, your program has undefined behaviour and you can expect all manner of weirdness to ensue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I'm reading, it might be important to use Wikipedia's brief explanation of what the **One Definition Rule** actually is:

> The One Definition Rule (ODR) is an important rule of the C++ programming language that prescribes that objects and non-inline functions cannot have more than one definition in the entire program and template and types cannot have more than one definition by translation unit.

This means that when the program is compiled, there can be *one*, ***and only one*** definition of a function or object. This might be confusing, however a **class** or **type** shouldn't be thought of as objects, they're really just **blueprints** for an object.

In your question, I think there's a misunderstanding of what `#include` does and how the **ODR** applies to classes. When the program is compiling, the `.cpp` files look to their `#include`'d class definitions as a way to *link* together, that is, the `class.h` **blueprint** must know where to look when calling it's member functions. Having multiple `#include`'s of the same `class.h` is not the same as having multiple definitions of `class.h`, and thus, it cannot violate the **One Definition Rule**.

Comment: That's not true - the ODR specifically calls out this case as being permitted, and it absolutely falls under the ODR's jurisdiction. I don't think the OP misunderstood anything.

Comment: OP is confused as to why multiple `#include`s of a `class.h` in two or more `classa.cpp`, and `classb.cpp` don't violate the ODR. The reason that it does not violate the rule is because it only ever has one definition - the compiler essentially just sews the .cpp and .h files together and they become a single definition. OP misunderstands that `#include` is not re-defining the class, it is merely **linking** it.

Comment: No, they are talking about the case of multiple translation units. Even if they weren't, there is no "sewing"/"linking" in the way that you describe ("they become a single definition" what?). You misunderstood the question.

Comment: _"If a header file has a definition of a class, for example ThisClass, and that header file is included in two other files for example a.cpp and b.cpp."_ That's **two** translation units.

Answer (score 0):

It is okay to have a class defined in a header file because the compiler treats the functions declared in the class in such a case as an inline functions.

So there are two options to happen when you call this class functions:

Or it wiil inline the function calls and in such a case there is no problem at all of multiple definition.

Or it wont inline them and in such a case he will create the symbols related to the functions as weak symbols. Then the linker will choose one of the symbols to be the symbol representing the function.

Of course if there will be different defintions in two or more cpp files there will be undefined behaviour.